# Incorrect exported data - How to split values in specific column and shift it to other columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I exported some data and this export did not work completely fine.

I read my data into a pandas dataframe and it now looks like this:

```
time A B C D E F
1 NaN nullnull0.54 0.74 0.89 NaN NaN
2 NaN nullnull0.01 3.32 1.19 NaN NaN
3 NaN nullnull1.89 0.65 4.50 NaN NaN
4 NaN nullnull4.64 2.87 2.22 NaN NaN
5 0.52 1.43 3.56 5.65 0.06 1.11
6 3.51 0.89 0.96 1.10 2.08 4.29
7 0.11 10.20 3.36 2.15 0.70 1.99
```

`time`is my first column and then I have six columns `A` to `F`.

Column A is correct. I did not get any data here. The problem begins in column `B`. For `B` and `C` I could actually not extract values other than this `null` values. But instead writing this `null` values in column `B` and `C` in my csv-file it writes `nullnull0.54` in column B and then fills columns C to F with the other extracted values and adds NaN values for `E` and `F`. I.e. values in `C` should be `E` and `D` should be in `F` for all the rows where this `nullnull` pattern is observed (and the numeric value in `B` should be added to `D`. That means, I would need to write a code which splits the value in `B` in three party `null`, `null` and `value` and then shift the numeric values two columns to the left beginning with this numeric value in `B` and only for rows where this `nullnull`-pattern is observed.

Edit:
The output should look like this:

```
time A B C D E F
1 NaN null null 0.54 0.74 0.89
2 NaN null null 0.01 3.32 1.19
3 NaN null null 1.89 0.65 4.50
4 NaN null null 4.64 2.87 2.22
5 0.52 1.43 3.56 5.65 0.06 1.11
6 3.51 0.89 0.96 1.10 2.08 4.29
7 0.11 10.20 3.36 2.15 0.70 1.99
```

I used this code to read the csv-file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path\to\file.csv',delimiter=';',names=['time','A','B','C','D','E','F'],index_col=False)
```

It is not due to the code I used to read the file. It is due to the export which went wrong. I also get this `nullnullxyz`-values in one column as outputs in my csv file.

Comment: Can you show the expected output explicitly?

Comment: please add the souce code for this output.

Comment: What code do you use to read the file? What is the file that you read looks like? It seems it does not recognize the columns correctly in the first place.

Comment: what file type are you read this information from? can you provide som example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest fixing the corrupt csv file, or better the root cause of the corruption, **before** loading it into pandas.

If you really have to do it in pandas, here is a slow-and-dirty fix using `.apply()`:

```
def fix(row: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    """Fix 'nullnull' assuming it occurs only in column B."""
    
    if str(row["B"]).startswith("nullnull"):
        return pd.Series([row["time"], row["A"], float('nan'), float('nan'), float(row["B"][8:]), row["C"], row["D"]],
                         index=df.columns)
    else:  # no need to fix
        return row

# apply the fix for each row
df2 = df.apply(fix, axis=1)
# column B is in object type originally
df2["B"] = df2["B"].astype(float)
```

### Output

```
print(df2)
   time     A      B     C     D     E     F
0   1.0   NaN    NaN   NaN  0.54  0.74  0.89
1   2.0   NaN    NaN   NaN  0.01  3.32  1.19
2   3.0   NaN    NaN   NaN  1.89  0.65  4.50
3   4.0   NaN    NaN   NaN  4.64  2.87  2.22
4   5.0  0.52   1.43  3.56  5.65  0.06  1.11
5   6.0  3.51   0.89  0.96  1.10  2.08  4.29
6   7.0  0.11  10.20  3.36  2.15  0.70  1.99
```

Also verify data types:

```
print(df2.dtypes)

time    float64
A       float64
B       float64
C       float64
D       float64
E       float64
```

Comment: It is solved, thanks a lot! And you are right: Actually I should solve the errors in the export. The problem is that the data is not avalaible anymore for the earliest time periods...